# Connect R script with selectizeInput in shiny

Tags: r, shiny, rstudio

I have an R script (let us call it myscript.R) which is a function of input$year.

Once I select the year in the shinyapp I want that the computer run "myscript.R" ?

I tried kind of the following structure,but it does not work

```
fun=function(input,ouput,session){
    year= input$year
}

observeEvent(input$year,{
    fun(input,output,session)
})
```

Your answers are appreciated!

Comment: Please share a minimum example showing what you've tried, including both your shiny app files and the other file. 

If you want to use a function from another script, you have to source it with `source("myscript.R")`. Then you can use `myfunction(input$year)` as if it were defined in the same file.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if a function from a script is really what you want here. If you want to make output dependent on input, this is how you do it in Shiny:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  selectInput("year","Year: ",choices=c(2000,2001,2002)),
  textOutput("test")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  test_reactive <- reactive({
    year = as.numeric(input$year)
    year = year + 1
    return(year)
  })

  output$test <- renderText({
    test_reactive()
  })
}

runApp(shinyApp(ui, server))
```

If you really want to call a function from a script, and within script.R you have a function, like:

```
my_function <- function(year)
{
...
}
```

You should do `source(script.R)` somewhere above the server function, and do `my_function(year)` where I have added 1 to the year.

Hope this helps.

Comment: thank you. But this is not what I want. Inside script.R , I have the variable input$year.

Comment: That's not possible as far as I know, you would have to create a function in your script.R and pass input$year as an argument, as I explained below the large code chunk in my answer.